# Changing color and marker of each point using seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this code slightly modified from [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/regression_marginals.html) :

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
color = sns.color_palette()[5]
g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, kind="reg", stat_func=None,
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12), color='k', size=7)

g.set_axis_labels('total bill', 'tip', fontsize=16)
```

and I get a nice looking plot - However, for my case I need to be able to change the color AND format of each individual point.

I've tried using the keywords, `marker`, `style`, and `fmt`, but I get the error `TypeError: jointplot() got an unexpected keyword argument`.

What is the correct way to do this? I'd like to avoid calling `sns.JointGrid` and plotting the data and marginal distributions manually..

Comment: Maybe I'm missunderstanding, but according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800944/changing-marker-style-in-scatter-plot-according-to-third-variable), you cannot pass a list of markers to `plt.scatter` and so the `seaborn` wrapper won't work either.

Comment: Shoot. I'll have to edit that. Maybe it would be possible to clear the points after the figure is created and plot each one individually

Comment: It ended up being not too hard. All I had to do was `g.ax_joint.cla()` to clear the axes where the points are plotted and then plot the points using the answer you mentioned. Regression is gone but I don't really need that part anyways just the points with the marginal distributions

Comment: Can you please answer your own question showing your code (and then accept it)? Even better if you can add an image so people in the future can have it as a reference :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solving this problem is almost no different than that from matplotlib (plotting a scatter plot with different markers and colors), except I wanted to keep the marginal distributions:

```
import seaborn as sns
from itertools import product
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
color = sns.color_palette()[5]
g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, kind="reg", stat_func=None,
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12), color='k', size=7)

#Clear the axes containing the scatter plot
g.ax_joint.cla()

#Generate some colors and markers
colors = np.random.random((len(tips),3))
markers = ['x','o','v','^','<']*100

#Plot each individual point separately
for i,row in enumerate(tips.values):
    g.ax_joint.plot(row[0], row[1], color=colors[i], marker=markers[i])

g.set_axis_labels('total bill', 'tip', fontsize=16)
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

The regression line is now gone, but this is all I needed.

Comment: `plt.scatter` doesn't have any way to control the marker used for individual points, so something like this is probably your best bet, but you can do `g.ax_joint.collections[0].set_visible(False)` instead of clearing the whole Axes, which will preserve the regression line.

Comment: Weirdly, this only worked when specifying the marker. Without that, it won't plot the points!

Comment: How did you know that `['x','o','v','^','<']` were the available marker styles? I'm finding the Seaborn documentation difficult to navigate. (EDIT: I think I found it  [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers))

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is too complicated. `plt.sca()` can be used to do this in a simpler way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, kind="reg", stat_func=None,
                  xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12))


g.ax_joint.cla() # or g.ax_joint.collections[0].set_visible(False), as per mwaskom's comment

# set the current axis to be the joint plot's axis
plt.sca(g.ax_joint)

# plt.scatter takes a 'c' keyword for color
# you can also pass an array of floats and use the 'cmap' keyword to
# convert them into a colormap
plt.scatter(tips.total_bill, tips.tip, c=np.random.random((len(tips), 3)))
```

Comment: I recommend skipping the call to `plt.sca` and using the axes object directly: `g.ax_joint.scatter(tips.total_bill, ...)`. Avoid the `pyplot` state-machine when possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can also directly precise it in the list of arguments, thanks to the keyword : `joint_kws` (tested with seaborn 0.8.1). If needed, you can also change the properties of the marginal with `marginal_kws`

So your code becomes :

```
import seaborn as sns
colors = np.random.random((len(tips),3))
markers = (['x','o','v','^','<']*100)[:len(tips)]

sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips, kind="reg",
    joint_kws={"color":colors, "marker":markers})
```

Answer (score 2):

1. In `seaborn/categorical.py`, find `def swarmplot`.
2. Add parameter `marker='o'` before `**kwargs`
3. In `kwargs.update`, add `marker=marker`.

Then add e.g. `marker='x'` as a parameter when plotting with `sns.swarmplot()` as you would with Matplotlib `plt.scatter()`.

Just came across the same need, and having `marker` as a `kwarg` did not work. So I had a brief look. We can set other parameters in similar ways.
https://github.com/ccneko/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/categorical.py

Only a small change needed here, but here's the GitHub forked page for quick reference ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use JointGrid, since jointplot is a wrapper that simplifies its usage.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.JointGrid("total_bill", "tip", data=tips)
g = g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, c=np.random.random((len(tips), 3)))
g = g.plot_marginals(sns.distplot, kde=True, color="k")
```

Answer (score -2):

The other two answers are complex extravagances (actually, they're by people who truly understand what's going on under the hood).

Here's an answer by someone who's just guessing. It works though!

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot("total_bill", "tip", data=tips,
              c=tips.day.cat.codes, cmap='Set1', stat_func=None,
              xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 12))
```

Comment: I don't think this works; I just tried it in seaborn 0.7.1 and got `ValueError: Supply a 'c' kwarg or a 'color' kwarg but not both; they differ but their functionalities overlap.` As nice as it would be if the `c` argument could be a collection, I don't think it can.